# Repeating a webBrowser1.Navigate with Timer or Interval?

Tags: c#

I can't figure out which is the best way to repeat a search on bing.

It has to be delayed 3-4 seconds and repeat. This is what I have so far.

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\dictionary.txt");
var r = new Random();
var randomLineNumber = r.Next(0, lines.Length - 1);
var line = lines[randomLineNumber];
//Repeat # entered in textBox2
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://bing.com/search?q=" + line);
```

I could use a Timer but I would need a way to automatically stop after X searches.

Comment: so set a counter and disable timer after it hits the X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be the solution;

Define a private integer field like this;

```
private static int counter=0;
```

Drop a **Timer** on your form,set its **Interval** property to 3000-4000 milliseconds
and double click the Timer on the designer, in the tick event write the 
following code;

```
counter++;
if(counter==5)// Replace 5 with how many times you want to repeat Navigate method.
{
   var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\dictionary.txt");
   var r = new Random();
   var randomLineNumber = r.Next(0, lines.Length - 1);
   var line = lines[randomLineNumber];
   //Repeat # entered in textBox2
   webBrowser1.Navigate("http://bing.com/search?q=" + line);
}
```

With that you're almost done,the only thing you need to do is call **timer1.Start();** whenever you want to start the procedure.Hope this gets your issue solved.

Comment: Works perfect, thank you. Although I believe you meant `if(counter<=5)`

Comment: Is there anyway to change the counter back to 0 after the timer has been started?

Comment: Figured it out. `Form1.counter = 0;` - Thank you for the help once again!